# Enhance Air ticket showing incorrect result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sabre

I am trying to post this JSON in post with URL

```
    $url = 'https://api.havail.sabre.com/v1.2.0/air/ticket';
        $headers2 = array(
        'Authorization: bearer '.$access_token,
        'protocol: HTTP 1.1 ',
        'Accept: */*',
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );


$postData ='{
  "AirTicketRQ": {
    "DesignatePrinter": {
      "Profile": {
        "Number": 1
      }
    },
    "Itinerary": {
      "ID": "VWKJJT"
    },
    "Ticketing": [{
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BSP_Ticketing": {
          "MultipleFOP": {
            "Fare": {
              "Amount": "100.00"
            },
            "FOP_One": {
              "CC_Info": {
                "Suppress": true,
                "PaymentCard": {
                  "Code": "VI",
                  "ExpireDate": "2016-11",
                  "ExtendedPayment": 12,
                  "Number": ***********1003
                }
              }
            },
            "FOP_Two": {
              "Type": "CK"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers": {
        "PriceQuote": [{
          "Record": [{
            "Number": 1,
            "Reissue": true
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BSP_Ticketing": {
          "MultipleFOP": {
            "Fare": {
              "Amount": "100.00"
            },
            "FOP_One": {
              "CC_Info": {
                "Suppress": true,
                "PaymentCard": {
                  "Code": "VI",
                  "ExpireDate": "2016-11",
                  "ExtendedPayment": 12,
                  "Number": ************1003
                }
              }
            },
            "FOP_Two": {
              "Type": "CA"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers": {
        "PriceQuote": [{
          "Record": [{
            "Number": 2,
            "Reissue": true
          }]
        }]
      }
    }],
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SPTEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}';

$ch2 = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, POST);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

//var_dump( $results = json_decode(curl_exec($ch2)));
$results["get_data"] = json_decode(curl_exec($ch2),true);
```

I tried to use GET method for some other API and it was working. But for Enhanced Air ticket I am getting wrong data in response.

First Part:

[image]

Second Part:
[image]

What is the printer error and all. I used some get APIs that worked but why this API showing those problems? What is the actual problem? Is my JSON is correct that I am sending in request?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this part of the code:

```
"DesignatePrinter": {
    "Profile": {
        "Number": 1
    }
},
```

If this used to work, the you probably done it in a different environment or PCC.